# Output not printing at all

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long t;
    long long * count= NULL;
    count=new long long[t];
   
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        long long n, i=0;
        long long * p= NULL;
        
        cin >> n;
        int c=0;
        
         p= new long long[n];
            for (i=0; i<n; i++)
                {
                cin >> p[i];
            }
            for (i=0; i<n; i++){
                    if(p[i]>=p[i+1]){
                        c++;
                        }
            }
        count[t]=c+1;
        
    }
   

 for(int i=0; i<t; i++){
    std::cout<<count[i];
    cout<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

// This is my code and the bold part is not printing the count array, please can anyone point out the mistake, is the count array going out of scope? //

Comment: `count=new long long[t];` what is the value of `t` here ??? And then what is the size of `count`?

Comment: `count=new long long[t];` you did this before you asked the value of `t`

Comment: By the way, you are leaking the buffer assigned to `p`. Though it may not be a big problem because there won't be too much input in this type of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the value of a variable **before** it gets a value.

```
count=new long long[t];

cin>>t;
```

should be

```
cin>>t;
count=new long long[t];
```

You did it right with `p` and `n` later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you did `count=new long long[t];` before reading values to `t`.
This means you used indeterminate value of uninitialized `t`, which is bad.
This line should be after `cin>>t;` and before the `while` loop.

Secondly, `t` is `-1` when the `while` loope ends, so `i<t` will become false.
You have to save the number somewhere.

Try this (assuming you want to print the results in the order of the input are given):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long t;
    long long * count= NULL;
   
    cin>>t;
    count=new long long[t];
    int count_idx = 0;
    while(t--){
        long long n, i=0;
        long long * p= NULL;
        
        cin >> n;
        int c=0;
        
        p= new long long[n];
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            cin >> p[i];
        }
        for (i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(p[i]>=p[i+1]){
                c++;
            }
        }
        count[count_idx++]=c+1;
        
    }
    

    for(int i=0; i<count_idx; i++){
        std::cout<<count[i];
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, `count_idx` is used to maintain where to write the results to retain the order and it will hold the number of data saved at the end of the `while` loop.
Also I fixed the indentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helped!